# Restrictions when using diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume

Tags: macos, terminal, hfs+, brute-force

I wrote a very simple brute force script on my Mac that runs the `$ diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume <UUID> -passphrase <PASSWORD>` command against a HFS+ encrypted drive by going through a dictionary of passwords. It's not very sophisticated, but the script did work when using small proof-of-concept dictionaries. My problem is that `diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume` appears to stop working after exactly 100 executions. In order to use the command again after the 100th attempt, I have to reboot my Mac. Does anyone know of a way to programmatically reset whatever is keeping track of the `diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume` execution count or bypass this restriction?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that you must run `diskutil` as sudo if you want to attempt unlocking a volume more than 100 times.